# ActiveAdmin returning undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have just installed ActiveAdmin on a brand new rails app and created a `product` model and an `active_admin:resource` with the same name.

After that I have inserted the following to start customising my form to create `product` items:

```
 index do
    column :email
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.input :email
    f.buttons
  end
```

But now, when I try to create a new `product`, once I click the "create" button it returns the following error:

```
undefined method `email' for #<Product id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes because you have not added any field called `email` in the Product model.

Comment: this is supposed to be admin_user.rb . have you places this in product.rb.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined method `email' for #<Product id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

means you are calling the `email` method on `Product` instance. Agreeing to the Athar's comment - you have simply mixed the files (`admin_user.rb` and `product.rb`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing AdminUser and Product models, seems like product table really doesn't have email column